# How to duplicate a certain set of JavaFX [2.2] nodes

Tags: java, javafx-2, nodes

I'm currently developing a drawing application in JavaFX for fun. I currently working on saving the contents of the drawing panel to an image. All the nodes that should be saved in that image are children of one Group. I want to use the scene snapshot method, but my problem is that I don't want to snapshot the whole scene...

Creating a new scene with the shapes group is obviously not an option since a group can only be part of one scenegraph at a time. Thus, I need a way to duplicate all the children of the shapes group in order to create a new scene that I can snapshot... Is there anyway to do this? Should I subclass the Group class and create a clone method or something? I don't really know how to proceed...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you want to do is snapshot a group.  In which case, use the [Node snapshot method](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot%28javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,%20javafx.scene.image.WritableImage%29) instead of the scene snapshot method.  You don't need to clone a scene graph node tree just to get a snapshot of it.

Comment: Ahh that's great! I was looking for that method but didn't quite manage to find it... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I thought of something... I used a CustomShape class that extended Group, and gave it an abstract method getShapeCopy. I made this method return a Rectangle (JavaFX node) for the CustomRectangle class, etc. This works perfectly!